# gnome-disks write caching

Tags: gnome, gnome3, disk, ssd, caching

in **RHEL/CentOS 7.9** anyway, when running `gnome-disks` which is under the Applications-Utilities-Disks menu, for a recognized SSD it offers the enabling of **write-cache**.

[image]

I would like to know what technically is happening when turning this on, that wasn't already happening.

*I was under the impression, whether it was an SSD or a conventional spinning hard disk, that linux inherently does **disk caching**.  This impression mainly comes from reading that [www.linuxatemyram.com](http://www.linuxatemyram.com) page years ago.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This controls the cache setting on the disk so it's not related to Linux or RAM, this controls how the disk itself caches the data in its internal memory before writing them to the disk permanent storage.

GNOME Disks (or UDisks to be correct) just sends an ATA command to the disk telling it to enable/disable the feature called *volatile write cache*. (Btw. in CLI `hdparm -W <0/1>` does the same thing.)

It's similar to any other write cache -- if you enable this, the disk will tell the OS the data have been written after saving it to the cache and the disk will write them to disk later (that's where the warning about data loss comes from).

Comment: regarding *data loss in the event of a power failure*, isn't that always the case even without enabling ATA disk write caching if we are simply talking about a power failure event happening?

Comment: There's always possibility of losing some data, but in this case you can have few hundred MiBs of data in the disk cache and filesystems thinks these are safely stored on the disk so even things like journal or CoW which normally help with preventing data loss won't help.

Comment: I have just tried `hdparm -W /dev/sdb`, gave me `1`. In Disks, this is disabled. So the GUI is probably not being initialized properly?